# Divide every row in a matrix by corresponding row in vector

Tags: r

Imagine I have the following matrix:

```
mat <- read.table(text="
   0 25  7 25  9 20 26 26 22 19 22 25
  25  0 21 43 23 37 43 43 41 33 36 46
   7 21  0 21 22 20 22 37 35 32 35 45
  25 43 21  0 26 35 43 43 38 33 37 49
   9 23 22 26  0 21 24 23 24 19 22 31
  20 37 20 35 21  0 34 34 39 39 43 51
  26 43 22 43 24 34  0 44 36 33 37 48
  26 43 37 43 23 34 44  0 50 47 51 77
  22 41 35 38 24 39 36 50  0 47 50 78
  19 33 32 33 19 39 33 47 47  0 73 79
  22 36 35 37 22 43 37 51 50 73  0 87
  25 46 45 49 31 51 48 77 78 79 87  0           
", header=F)

mat <- as.matrix(mat)
```

I want to compute a specific network density measure which is defined as: 
[image]

where Z_ijk is the number of co-occurrences between team members i and  j , and max(Z_ijk) is the maximum number of co-occurrences that team member i  has with any other member of team k. N_k is the number of members on the team.

To get the maximum value in each row, I did the following:

```
max_values <- apply(mat, 1, max)

> max_values
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 
26 46 45 49 31 51 48 77 78 79 87 87
```

I thought I could divide the matrix by max_values using sweep:

```
sweep(mat, 1, max_values, FUN = '/')
```

But it does not yield the intended output.  Any thoughts?

The expected output would be: divide every value in row 1 by 26, every value in row 2 by 46, and so on.

Comment: I added a verbal description

Comment: The code you are using is doing that `divide every value in row 1 by 26, every value in row 2 by 46, and so on.`

Comment: Haha!  You're right.  The elusive self-answering question on StackOverflow.  I don't know what I was thinking

Comment: With `sweep` specified the `MARGIN` as 1, it does the rowwise application of function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this by dividing with `rowMaxs` (from `matrixStats`)

```
library(matrixStats)
mat/rowMaxs(mat)
```

Comment: I notice this doesn't work with sparseMatrices, which is what I'm using due to the fact that my actual dataset is massive.  Any thoughts on an efficient way to compute the above statistic with sparseMatrices?

Comment: @Parseltongue  Did you meant that there is a warning?  For this data, it does work, `out <- mat/rowMaxs(mat); out2 <- Matrix(mat, sparse = TRUE)/rowMaxs(mat); identical(out, as.matrix(out2))#[1] TRUE`

Comment: I'm sorry, try reading in the data without the first column.  I've edited the data with a deleted first column.  I'm getting the error:

`Error in rowMaxs(mat) : Argument 'x' must be a matrix or a vector.`

Comment: @Parseltongue  Have you converted `mat` to a different object?

Comment: Did you try loading in the new data and seeing if it works?  I converted it to a sparse matrix using the exact above code, and am still getting that problem.